# Apache Default Page Showing When HTTPS Using Django Project

Tags: apache-2.2, apache2

I have been trying for the past 1 week to get this to work but it just does not seem to be working at all. Please help, here are the files for the default-ssl and the 001-default, the website is working fine on the http but is not working on https. -

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin eren9zero@gmail.com
    ServerName essayeshop.com
    ServerAlias www.essayeshop.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
            nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
            downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
</VirtualHost>
```

```
ServerName essayeshop.com
ServerAdmin eren9zero@gmail.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


Alias /static /home/nick/website/static
<Directory /home/nick/website/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/nick/website/website>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess website python-path=/home/nick/website python-home=/home/nick/website/env
WSGIProcessGroup website
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/nick/website/website/wsgi.py
# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName  essayeshop.com
  ServerAlias www.essayeshop.com
  DocumentRoot  /var/www/html

  WSGIDaemonProcess essayeshop.com \
    python-home=/path/to/.virtualenv/mysite/ \
    python-path=/path/to/mysite/

  WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite/wsgi.py \
   process-group=mysite.com \
   application-group=%{GLOBAL}

  <Directory /path/to/mysite>
    <Files wsgi.py>
      Require all granted
    </Files>
  </Directory>

  <Directory /path/to/.virtualenvs/mysite>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  <Directory /path/to/mysite/logs>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  Alias /media/ /path/to/mysite/media/
  Alias /static/ /path/to/mysite/static/

  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/mysite-error.log
  LogLevel warn
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/mysite-access.log combined

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /path/to/cert/cert.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/cert/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

We need to install mod-wsgi, which is an apache module for the implmenentation of python WSGI.

Enable site and required mods

```
a2enmod ssl rewrite headers wsgi alias
```

and restart apache services

Comment: **mod_wsgi** is probably already enabled in OP's configuration, since the default port `80` virtual host is _"working"_. The `WSGI*` directives can be also migrated to the global server config.

Comment: Tried doing this, getting the error at definition of wsgi process @sanjayparmar

Comment: @NikunjDutt plz refer - https://pawelzny.com/server/django/2018/02/26/the-most-complete-apache2-config-for-wsgi-django-and-drf/